# failing to import javascript css files

Tags: php, javascript, html

I look at this site: 
http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/examples/bbcode/

and tried to do this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../latest/markitup/skins/markitup/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../latest/markitup/sets/default/style.css" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../latest/markitup/jquery.markitup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../latest/markitup/sets/default/set.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()    {
                $('#bbcode').markItUp(myBbcodeSettings);
            });
</script>

</head>

<body>

 <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/>


 <table width="600" align="center">
   <tr>

     <td>
     Title:
    </td>

     <td>
        <input type="text" name="title" style="width:660px"/>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>

    <td valign="top">
     Message:
    </td>

     <td>

               <textarea id="bbcode" cols="80" rows="20">
                    ...BBCode stuff...
                </textarea>
     </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
     <td align="center" colspan="2">
               <input type="submit" name="send" value="send"/>
     </td>
   </tr>

 </table>
```

The problem is that no style is being applied (there is also a jason file, but I dont care, it should work, as it refers to the same id in the javascript command.

I checked the links..they are relative to their root..I dont understand, why I get a mistake!!!

EDIT:

NEVER MIND, I SOLVED IT. I CREATED NEW CSS JAVASCRIPT AND COPIED AND PASTED THE CODE

Comment: Are your files correctly loaded?

Comment: I dont know, their path is correct , I checked

Answer (score -1):

if these files are at your docroot, then just remove the ".." the loading should resolve.  i would suggest setting up a proper docroot by separating all your files by type like img, js, and css, then move them into those directories.

Comment: okay, I got it to work but the css pictures are not in place.. how can I reference this..background-image:url(images/bold.png); do I need to change the place..cause the icon picutures dont work

Comment: yes, use the same defined reference, but if my comment helped, i'm not sure why you down voted me :(